# How do I prevent Libreoffice from stubbornly focusing on the cursor?

Tags: libreoffice

If I am editing a Libreoffice Writer document and the cursor is, say, in page 3 but I keep reading and am now in page 5, upon saving focus will jump back to page 3, where the cursor is.

I find this very distracting. Is it a bug? Can I change this behavior somehow, so that LO stops second-guessing where I want the focus to be?

Comment: Sorry to say this is a bug still that will not likely get fixed. The only real option is to click on the page every time you scroll to a new one.

Comment: is there a bug report I could add my +1 to?

Comment: Looks like there will be a fix eventually. https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41063

Answer (score 0):

I also find the LibO editor jumps around all over the place.  It doesn't only do it when you save, but also when it automatically security saves itself.
I guess it's a feature that will never get fixed.
Sorry!

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Do you know if this has been filed as a bug, and if so, can you post a link to a "won't fix" statement by the developers?